Why is JPA still working with record class as entity?
Based on all the documentation I have read the following code should not work;Java records are immuatble and would not work with JPA. However the following code works. I can succesfully retrieve data from the database. Is it that JPA can support Java records in read-only scenarios ?
@Embeddable
public record TaxableLimitAmountId(@Column(name = "TAX_YR") String taxYr,
        @Column(name = "TAXL_LMT_UID") int taxableLimitUniqueId,
        @Column(name = "EFF_STDT", columnDefinition = "DATE") Date effectiveStartDate)
        implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TableName", schema = "schema")
public record TaxableLimitAmountEntity(
        @EmbeddedId TaxableLimitAmountId taxableLimitAmountId,
        @Column(name = "TAXL_LMT_AMT", columnDefinition = "DECIMAL") BigDecimal taxableLimitAmount,
        @Column(name = "EFF_ENDT", columnDefinition = "DATE") Date effectiveEndDate,
        @Column(name = "INSRT_TS") Timestamp insertTimeStamp,
        @Column(name = "LU_TS") Timestamp updateTimeStamp) {

}

public record FicaMaxData(int taxYr, BigDecimal taxableLimitAmount) {

}

@Repository
public interface TaxableLimitAmountRepo
        extends JpaRepository<TaxableLimitAmountEntity, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT NEW gov.ssa.irsrptg.repo.FicaMaxData(CAST(tla.taxableLimitAmountId.taxYr as INTEGER),tla.taxableLimitAmount) FROM TaxableLimitAmountEntity tla "
            + "WHERE tla.taxableLimitAmountId.taxableLimitUniqueId = 1")
    List<FicaMaxData> getFicaMaxAllYears();

    @Query("SELECT tla.taxableLimitAmount FROM TaxableLimitAmountEntity tla "
            + "WHERE tla.taxableLimitAmountId.taxableLimitUniqueId = 1 and tla.taxableLimitAmountId.taxYr = :taxYr")
    BigDecimal getFicaMaxSpecificYear(@Param("taxYr") String taxYr);
}



Hibernate gives the following warning but it doesn't throw any errors
o.h.m.i.EntityInstantiatorPojoStandard   : HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: gov.ssa.irsrptg.repo.TaxableLimitAmountEntity (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)

I'm using Java 17, Spring Boot 3.2.6, Spring Data Jpa 3.2.6, and Hibernate 6.4.8.Final

This is kind of cheating though, you are doing a select new which is not "normal" JPA, it is "work around issues with conventions" JPA. I wonder if it would still work if you do a regular select bla from TaxableLimitAmountEntity bla. It might, records are basically syntactic sugar. But without official support, I wouldn't risk it.

getFicaMaxAllYears() doesn't even create instances of TaxableLimitAmountEntity but only uses the meta information to create the SQL query and do the mapping into the FicaMaxData constructor. Apart from that Hibernate should be able to create a record instance via reflection (as Gimby said records are more syntactic sugar albeit reflection also gets some constraints on records) and thus be able to load those instances - maybe they'd even be detached as changes to them would not be expected.

@Gimby select without the new does cause the code to break.

JPA doesn't require throwing exceptions for records: Anything not specified is just unsupported - use at your own risk.  That it can be read from the database and instances built is due to implementation details of specific JPA providers, but won't be consistent. Writing or changes in the DB might cause things to blow up as JPA requires maintaining object identity - which means updating values for cached entities when there are changes

The statement "JPA does not work with records for entities" is a short form for: "There are things that JPA requires from an entity that aren't possible with records".
The hard limit here is the immutability, which prevents JPA to work as intended by tracking changes to the entity.
Of course this doesn't mean that a JPA implementation has to immediately blow up in your face if it encounters a record. Some things might work just fine, because those features aren't necessary for the use case.
For example you don't need a default constructor, when you use a constructor expression.
Or your JPA implementation might work around some limitations of JPA, as Hibernate seems to do for the lack of a default constructor, a hinted at by

No default (no-argument) constructor for class: gov.ssa.irsrptg.repo.TaxableLimitAmountEntity (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)

So yes: some stuff might work.
So far I haven't seen an official statement by JPA or Hibernate what kind of stuff works and I would be reluctant to rely on features that just happen to work, since they might stop working with the next release.
